# How to convert readable stream to buffer in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, sharp

I have an endpoint in my NextJS app, where I'm creating read stream from a file path

```
const fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path)
```

I'm using SharpJS to compress files that are images. However, Sharp doesn't accept ReadableStreams, but rather buffer or Uint8Array.
How can I convert a Readable Stream to buffer?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `fs.readFile` to get a buffer from the start?

Comment: `fs.readFile` returns a buffer by default. Have a look here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions

Comment: Maybe this other post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176456/stream-file-content-to-the-client-using-nextjs-app-router
The question is a bit confuse I think, `fs.ReadStream` is not a web platform `ReadableStream` either